# Rearrangement of $13$ people passing books to each other where no one passes books to same person

Tags: probability, combinatorics

**EDIT:** I still don't understand the answer Math Lover already gave. I'd like an answer that explicitly builds on my attempt/thoughts and goes step by step in detail, hence bountying my question.

## Actual Question

Here's yet another problem from my probability textbook:

> A reading society of $13$ members passes books in circular rotation from member to member in defined order. If for a new year the order be rearranged at random, what is the chance that no one will pass his books to the same member as in the previous years?

Here's what I did. Without loss of generality let's say the initial passing order of members is from $x_1$ to $x_2$ to $x_3$ etc. all the way up to $x_{13}$ to $x_1$. Let's first calculate the denominator. We start with $x_1$, and then we have $12$ choices for the next member, then $11$, all the way down to $1$, so the denominator either $12!$ or $12! - 1$, depending on whether or not we include the initial arrangement in what the problem statement calls "the order be rearranged at random".

Let's next calculate the numerator. We start with $x_1$, and then we have $11$ choices for the next member since we can't use $x_2$, and then we have $10$ choices for the next member since we can't use the member that was ahead of that member in the initial configuration, all the way down to $1$, so the numerator is $11!$.

Therefore the desired probability is either ${1\over{12}}$ or ${{11!}\over{12! - 1}}$.

However, this is certainly not correct since we're undercounting i.e. consider a rearrangement that begins with $x_1x_3x_2$. Then there were $11$ choices for the second slot, $10$ choices for the third slot. But then there's $10$ choices again for the fourth slot because $x_3$ is before $x_2$ in the passing order. So what do I need to add to the probability I calculated to account for this phenomenon?

Comment: What about thinking derangement such that $$\frac{D_{12}}{12!}= \frac{176,214,841}{479,001,600} = 0.36787994413$$

Comment: I typically refer to the conflict between your method and that of Math Lover as the direct approach versus Inclusion-Exclusion.  Inclusion-Exclusion is generally preferred because of the specific issue that your question raised: "...So what do I need to add to the probability I calculated to account for this phenomenon".  The only way that I know of to apply the direct approach is to break the situation up into cases, then sub-cases, then sub-sub-cases, and so on.  So, $x_1x_3x_5$ could be one case and $x_1x_3x_2$ would be a 2nd case.  ...see next comment

Comment: If you examine [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) you may notice the possibility of a 3rd method - recursion.  I suggest that you accept that the direct approach is unworkable, and either attempt recursion, or study Math Lover's answer line by line.  If you opt for Math Lover's answer, then every time that you come to a question in his analysis that you don't understand, leave a message following his answer, giving him a chance to step up.  If he doesn't, flag me with a message and I will respond with a comment or invite you to a chat. ...see next comment

Comment: In order to use Inclusion-Exclusion, you have to master it.  Let $A_k$ represent all of the possible arrangements where $x_k$ passes to $x_{(k+1)}.$  Let $T_r$ denote $$\sum_{1 \leq i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_r \leq 13} \left|A_{i_1} \cap A_{i_2} \cap \cdots \cap A_{i_r}\right|.$$  That is, $T_r$ will involve $\binom{13}{r}$ terms.  Then, the numerator will be $$[(12)!] - \left|A_1 \cup \cdots \cup A_{13}\right| = [(12)!] - \sum_{r=1}^{13} \left[(-1)^{r+1} T_r\right].$$

Comment: I answered and then answered the lone question I received to my answer, never realized the question was as active as ever and I didn't even know it :) I offer, like I do for every single answer I provide on the site, to engage till OP is satisfied that they understand my answer or we mutually give up on that hope :) :)

Comment: @MathLover I don't think that the issues that the OP has are necessarily with your analysis, and I question whether straightforward responses can resolve all of his uncertainty.  In my opinion, it takes sophisticated intuition to understand the validity of Inclusion-Exclusion for this problem, and this sophistication requires experience.  Personally, I (more than once) have made mistakes trying to write a mathSE answer using Inclusion-Exclusion.  Then, it finally sunk in.  I question whether there is a shortcut to developing one's intuition.

Answer (score 4):

You will have to apply Principle of Inclusion Exclusion.

There are $12! ~ $ circular permutations without restriction.

Now if one of them is passing book to the same person, that gives us $11!$ ways of passing books and there are $13$ ways to choose the person. So we subtract $13 \cdot 11!$.

If two of them are passing book to the same persons, we have $10!$ permutations and $ \displaystyle {13 \choose 2}$ ways of choosing those two people.

So applying Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion, number of desired permutations are

$\displaystyle \left[\sum_{i=0}^{12} (-1)^i{13 \choose i} (12-i)! \right] - 1$

The last $(-1)$ is to subtract the permutation where all of them are passing book to the same next person as current.

Dividing it by $12!$ will give the desired probability.

Also see, https://oeis.org/A000757

Comment: Thanks @Math Lover. Unfortunately I don't see how you get "Now if one of them is passing book to the same person, that gives us $11!$ ways of passing books and there are $13$ ways to choose the person. So we subtract $13\cdot11!$". Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @EmperorConcerto we call persons as $A, B, C, D, ....$. We choose $A$ from $13$ persons. Say in the original arrangement, $A$ was passing book to $B$ and continues to pass the book to $B$ so club $A$ and $B$ together. That leaves $12$ persons (counting $AB$ as one). So that gives $(12-1)!$ circular permutations.

Answer (score 1):

Basically same as @Math Lover's answer.

Total number of ways: $12!$

To that we must substract the prohibited arrangements.

The pair $x_1, x_2$, for example, is prohibited, because the $x_1$ element is "wrong", it has on its side the same element as in the original. There $11!$ arrangements (circular permutations) that include that case. Because the posible wrong elements are 13, we must multiply that count by $13$, or $\binom{13}{1}$.

But we are overcounting: to the above we must substract the arrangements with two or more "wrong elements. Fixing any two "wrong" elements, we have $10!$ arrangements that include them. Which we must multiply by $\binom{13}{2}$.

And so on.. This is the inclusion-exclusion principle at work.

Then the total count of allowed arrangements is

$$ 12! - \binom{13}{1} 11 ! + \binom{13}{2} 10 ! + \cdots  $$

Answer (score 0):

We can use the multiplicative principle for this problem.

We know that there are 12! ways to rearrange 13 people at a circular table. Now, we need to count how many of these permutations satisfy the condition that they don't have two or more consecutive people in both permutations (the one from last year and the new one).

Then by inclusion-exclusion lemma we can count the bad cases and substract them.

Comment: i hope this is more clear now as I change some mistakes it had when i post it